# Can't run puppet with modules on vagrant

Tags: puppet, vagrant, provisioning

I was studing puppet and running the manifests happened without a problem but when I added modules to puppet I run into the following issue:

---

`DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
 INFO interface: info: Running Puppet with db.pp...
 INFO interface: info: ==> db: Running Puppet with db.pp...
==> db: Running Puppet with db.pp...
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute:  puppet apply --verbose --debug --modulepath '/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-9f098f5eef3eb89ba69e9481e2fa4839:/etc/puppet/modules' --detailed-exitcodes --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513 /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513/db.pp (sudo=true)
DEBUG ssh: stderr: stdin: is not a tty`

`INFO interface: info: stdin: is not a tty
 INFO interface: info: ==> db: stdin: is not a tty
==> db: stdin: is not a tty
DEBUG ssh: stdout: warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
 INFO interface: info: warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
 INFO interface: info: ==> db: warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
==> db: warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
DEBUG ssh: stdout:`

`DEBUG ssh: stderr: Could not find class msql-server for precise32 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513/db.pp:59 on node precise32
 INFO interface: info: Could not find class msql-server for precise32 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513/db.pp:59 on node precise32
 INFO interface: info: ==> db: Could not find class msql-server for precise32 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513/db.pp:59 on node precise32
==> db: Could not find class msql-server for precise32 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-a11d1078b1b1f2e3bdea27312f6ba513/db.pp:59 on node precise32`

---

Aparently Vagrant is not using modules as described in this vagrant file (in the db machine section):

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|


config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.define :db do |db_config|
    db_config.vm.network :private_network,
                         :ip => "192.168.33.10"
    db_config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
        puppet.module_path = "modules"
        puppet.manifest_file = "db.pp"
        puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define :web do |web_config|
    web_config.vm.network :private_network,
                          :ip => "192.168.33.12"
    web_config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
        puppet.module_path = "modules"
        puppet.manifest_file = "web.pp"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define :monitor do |monitor_config|
    monitor_config.vm.network :private_network,
                              :ip => "192.168.33.14"
  end
end
```

Any clue on what's going on?

**EDITED**

I was able to figure out... it was a sintax issue in puppet. But now I have another issue

::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type msql::db

The resource type is used in the manifest:

```
include mysql::server

msql::db { "loja":   schema   => "loja_schema",   password => "xxxx", }
```

The definition is bellow:

```
define mysql::db($schema, $user = $title, $password) {
  #Dependência
  Class['mysql::server'] -> Mysql::db[$title]

  exec { "$title-schema":
    unless  => "mysql -uroot $schema",
    command => "mysqladmin -uroot create $schema",
    path  => "/usr/bin/",
  }

  exec {"$title-user":
    unless  => "mysql -u$user -p$password $schema",
    command => "mysql -uroot -e \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \
                                  $schema.* TO '$user'@'%' \
                                  IDENTIFIED BY '$password';\"",
    path    => "/usr/bin/",
    require => Exec["$title-schema"],
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to be sure puppet.module_path point to an existing directory, If you have /home/pippo/vagrant/fedora22/Vagrantfile with your config you need to have your puppet modules installed in /home/pippo/vagrant/fedora/modules

Comment: Yes... I did that. My directory is with the following folders and files:
README.md          allow_external.cnf loja_virtual.cfg   modules            tomcat.xml
Vagrantfile        context.xml        manifests          tomcat             tomcat7

Comment: @FernandaMartins could you post the cause/solution to your original issue as an answer? For the new problem, please open a new Question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by including module's classes into the manifest file pointed by Vagrant.

Example:

Inside manifests/db.pp add:

```
include <module name>::<class name>
```